How to change TOC font style
I need to change the styles of titles both in TOC and in the text according to the rules:

Chapters: boldface and make uppercase
Sections: boldface
Subsections: boldface and italics
Subsubsections: italics

I have the MWE below. The rules are correctly applied to the text, but the first one is not to the TOC.
The commented commands apply format the text, but mess with references:
% \let\newchapter\chapter
% \renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{%
%     \newchapter{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
%     \thispagestyle{fancy}
% }

Can anyone help me to accomplish it? Thanks!
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright]{memoir}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%----------> SETUP TOC <----------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%--> Change TOC title
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}

%--> Change TOC title style
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\fontsize{12}{12}\bfseries\centering}

%--> Remove vertical space before TOC title
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{}

%--> Remove vertical space after TOC title
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-1\baselineskip}}

%--> Add dotted lines for chapter levels in TOC
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}

%--> Adjust the alignment of the levels in TOC
\cftsetindents{part}{0em}{3.5em}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{3.5em}
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{3.5em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0em}{3.5em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{0em}{3.5em}

\newcommand{\TableOfContents}{%
    \cleardoublepage %... inicia próxima página ímpar
    
    %... Fazer sumário listar até subseções (tocdepth=4)
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
    
    \tableofcontents* %... o asterisco previne o sumário de listar-se a si mesmo
        \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    \cleardoublepage

    \setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}
    %... ajusta a indentação de parágrafo de texto após o sumário
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%---------> SETUP TITLES <--------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%--> Format titles in text
\titleformat{\chapter}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thechapter}{0.4em}{\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\section}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.4em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}{\thesubsection}{0.4em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{0.4em}{}

%--> Format titles in TOC
% \let\newchapter\chapter
% \renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{%
%     \newchapter{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
%     \thispagestyle{fancy}
% }

\let\newsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
    \newsection{\textbf{#1}}
}

\let\newsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{%
    \newsubsection{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
}

\let\newsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{%
    \newsubsubsection{\textit{#1}}
}

%--> Configure numbering levels
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%------> SETUP REFERENCES <-------%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{cite}

\nobibintoc
%... removes automatic title in TOC

%--> New command to generate bibliography
\newcommand*\MakeBibliography{%
    \cleardoublepage
    %... begins new odd page
    
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{TABLE OF REFERENCES}
    %... changes reference title
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\bibname}
    %... add reference title to TOC
    
    \titleformat{\chapter}%
        {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\centering}{}{}{}
        %... formats font and positioning of references title
    
    %... make sure the \leftmark and the \rightmark will be printed correctly
    \phantomsection
    
    %... make sure the bibliography pages will be fancy
    \def\thispagestyle##1{}
    
    \bibliographystyle{abntex2-num}
    %... aplica a norma ABNT às referências
    
    \bibliography{_bib}
    %... gera as referências bibliográficas
}


\begin{document}

    \TableOfContents
    
    \chapter{This is the first chapter}
    In this chapter I will present some concepts...
    
    \section{Title of the first section}
    You can confirm the concepts by looking at the references.\cite{Ref1}
    
    \subsection{The amazing subsection}
    
    \subsubsection{Ordinary subsubsection}
    
    \MakeBibliography

\end{document}

